# How To Display YouTube Channel On Page

Tags: nodes, files

I'm attempting my first Drupal site and would like to show a simple listing of the 5 most recent YouTube videos submitted (http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_recent?max-results=5).  I've been struggling with this for almost a week now and cannot get what I want.

I've tried Feeds and the YouTube parser and I've tried the Media Module as described [here](http://drupal.org/node/1358558).  I can get the 5 most recent videos imported as separate nodes, but I want to just be able to list them, embedded, on the single page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm new to Drupal and really looking for a walk-through at this point.  I'm using Drupal 7.19.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try Aggregator? It's the first one listed on the modules page then on the configuration page it's call Feed Aggregator.

I then use Views to style my results.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have played with that as well, but guess I just don't know enough to get it to work like I want.  Do you know of a tutorial that can walk me through it?

Comment: What kind of styling are try to do? For instance I display tweets and what I do is create a Block View. Format: unformatted list. Show: fields. Then for my Fields I have Aggregator Body. When you select that field you will get a pop up to configure that field. Here I select Rewrite Results then check rewrite the output of this field. You then select your replacement pattern to use and style the output of each feed.

Comment: Make sure when you create the view you select Show Aggregator Item

Comment: Come to think of it, if you can get the videos to show as nodes you should be able to create a view of those nodes so they are all on one page.

Comment: Can you point me to a tutorial that explains how to use a view for the nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Come to think of it, if you can get the videos to show as nodes you should be able to create a view of those nodes so they are all on one page.

Comment: Can you point me to a tutorial that explains how to use a view for the nodes?

Comment: OK, I'm back to having the individual nodes but I can't get the video, just the title which is a link that takes me back to youtube.

Comment: Were you ever able to view the youtube video?

Comment: I was able to get a listing on a single page using the Feed Importer module a view, but I cannot get the videos to display like I wanted - embedded.  They're just links off to youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the URL to embed? If so, you just need to theme the imported entities outputting that URL in the right format. If using the Field UI to customize the view modes of these entities, modules such as [Link iframe formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_iframe_formatter) may help.

Answer (score 0):

From your Dashboard, navigate to Appearance » Widgets. Then, under Available Widgets, click on the YouTube Feed widget. Choose which area you'd like to display it on, and click on Add Widget to save your choice. After doing this, check out your website and see your channel feed nicely displayed on your sidebar.